# How do I have an instance available globally in Objective-C (iOS 6 app)?

Tags: objective-c, ios, object, ios6, instance

Brand new to objective-C and iOS development (from a C background). I'm writing an app using the tab bar controller and using multiple views. I want to initialise an object when the app starts and then have that instance available to all the views.

Currently in my AppDelegate.m, I have:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    id myObject;
    myObject = [[MYObject alloc] init];

    return YES;
}
```

How do I access myObject for my other view controllers?

Thanks! (and excuse the newbie question)

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, there are numerous options:

**Singleton pattern:**

```
+ (id)sharedFoo {
    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    static FooClass *cSharedInstance = nil;

    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{ cSharedInstance = [[super alloc] init]; });
    return cSharedInstance;
}
```

...and access the object `[Foo sharedFoo]` throughout.  Some developers shun the singleton class because it risks creating not just a "god class", but something of a pantheon of such classes when the developer realizes that more and more objects need to become global.  Often that impulse is related to incompletely thinking about the design of the application.  A variation on the singleton idea uses a singleton to hold references to all global data, e.g. `[MyApplicationData sharedData]`...  Personally, I consider it a little cleaner than using the `UIApplication`'s delegate for this purpose.

**Dependency injection:**

Since you are using a `UITabBarController` design, you could use dependency injection (via `UITabBarControllerDelegate` methods such as `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:`) to propagate the object when the user selects a tab, then further propagate it down the controller hierarchy.

**Application delegate as owner:**

Like the singleton class, this risks creating a class with excessive responsibilities.  No only is the `UIApplication` delegate responsible for application lifecycle, it becomes responsible for all sorts of other states and behaviors that aren't related.  However, this pattern is widely used in code that I see.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of possibilities.
Just declare the object outside any class implementation, like in plain-old C. Or you could use a singleton class as storage for all your global data.

Answer (score 0):

you might use singleton pattern:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW32